# fscanf is not reading a double in a file. File is fine

Tags: c, scanf

Any idea why I get 0.000000 with this printf? I checked the file and it was created fine

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    double doub1;
    FILE *p;
    if((p=fopen("data.txt","wb+"))==NULL)
        puts("no");
    fprintf(p,"%lf@%lf\n%lf%s",3.9458,314.32133,32.3,"hello");
    fscanf(p,"%lf",&doub1);
    printf("%lf",doub1);
}
```

Comment: If opening the file fails you should exit, instead of going on to try to read and write anyway

Comment: Check results of `fscanf()`.  If not `1`, then `printf("%lf",doub1);` is meaningless.

Comment: Note: Since code is reading/writing text, suggest dropping the `'b'` in `"wb+"`.

Answer (score 2):

To write to a stream opened with `+` and read from the same stream you need to flush the output first:

```
fflush(p);
```

However this does not reposition the file position indicator. To read characters you already wrote, you need to seek back to them. There is not a separate file position indicator for reading and writing:

```
fseek(p, 0, SEEK_SET);    // go to start of file
```

The `fseek` does an implicit flush so you don't need to do `fflush` if you are doing `fseek`.

Also, you should check the return value of `fscanf` before trying to print the output. If the scan failed then you are printing an uninitialized variable.